# Tasks: TOP => redmine:plugins:migrate => environment

Tags: redmine

I do not understand
Error, but you want to place the SCM Creator plugin to Redmine
ubuntu15.04
gem 2.2.2

$ sudo mkdir /usr/share/redmine/plugins

$ wget http://projects.andriylesyuk.com/attachments/download/563/redmine_scm-0.5.0b.tar.bz2

$ sudo tar xfj redmine_scm-0.5.0b.tar.bz2 -C /usr/share/redmine/plugins/

$ cd /usr/share/redmine/

$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data plugins/redmine_scm/

$ sudo rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Observer

Tasks: TOP => redmine:load_default_data => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Please tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin is only compatible compatible with Redmine 2.4, 2.5, and 1.4 as is documented on the project's website at http://projects.andriylesyuk.com/project/redmine/scm-creator.

You have to either use another plugin or downgrade your Redmine version.